# Plot.ly scatter, automatic conversion

Tags: python, plotly

I recently moved to using Plot.ly libraries for Python (3) inside Jupyter notebooks. I came accross this "annoying" behavior, automatic conversion from strings to floats. Here is a minimal example

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.offline.init_notebook_mode()

data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=["200", "100", "300"],
        y=[1, 2, 3]
    )
]

py.offline.iplot(dict(data=data))
```

The sequence of abscissa should be as stated by `x` but it is not, it goes as `[100, 200, 300]`. If `x` is changed to, *e.g.*, `["a200","a100","a300"]`, then the order is maintained.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour (to include a blank space does not work)?

Thanks,
F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, set:

layout=dict( xaxis=dict(type='category') )

Described here:

https://plot.ly/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-type